# Is a way to make chrome/chromium to throw exception when frozen object mutated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Say, if I do the following in FireFox it will throw an exception:

```js
var ddd = {a:1, b:2}
Object.freeze(ddd);
'use strict'; ddd.a = 3; //throws a TypeError: "a" is read-only
```

But chrome / **chromium** does not. Is there a way to make them throw?

Comment: try `(function(){'use strict';var ddd={a:1, b:2};Object.freeze(ddd);ddd.a = 3; }());` and readup on how "use strict" should be utilized at the top of a program.

Comment: If I move the 'use strict' to be the first line of a function and then run it it Chrome for Android then I get the error you were expecting.

Comment: @nnnnnn: it can be the first part of a script file as well; the top of a "program".